# Nodejs local-dependency hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, serial-port, npm-install

People I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

When I install the following modules globally, they install like a charm.  No errors, no issues, no fuss.

`[1]npm --add-python-to-path install --global --production windows-build-tools`

`[2]npm install prebuild-install -global -verbose`

`[3]npm install node-gyp -global -verbose`

`[4]npm install serialport -g -verbose --build-from-source`

`[5]npm install johnny-five -global -verbose`

The moment I cd into my projects folder and try to install the 'serialport' and 'johnny-five' modules "locally", *(without -g)* I consistently get errors.  I've re-installed node and npm and googled my buty off but I can't find a solution.

**What the hell am I doing wrong?** Why do the modules install globally without fault but not locally?

Project is called 'arduvue2'

Error message when installing 'serialport' locally:

`2785 warn arduvue2@1.0.0 No repository field.
2786 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\arduvue2\node_modules\ansi-wrap' -> 'C:\arduvue2\node_modules.ansi-wrap.DELETE'
2787 verbose cwd C:\arduvue2
2788 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
2789 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "serialport" "-s" "-verbose" "--build-from-source"
2790 verbose node v8.11.1
2791 verbose npm  v5.6.0
2792 error path C:\arduvue2\node_modules\ansi-wrap
2793 error code ENOENT
2794 error errno -4058
2795 error syscall rename
2796 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\arduvue2\node_modules\ansi-wrap' -> 'C:\arduvue2\node_modules.ansi-wrap.DELETE'
2797 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2798 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]`

Comment: did you try to delete your `node_modules` dir and reinstalled everything from start?

Comment: Unless you omitted important info, it seems very unlikely that this will help, but: running Node in the Windows Subsystem for Linux, I've gotten similar errors when trying to `npm install` with Sublime, or, lately, Vim, open. Closing the text editors solved the problem and allowed the install to run correctly.

Comment: I deleted the node_modules folder.  Didn't work.  Does the 'prefix' have any influence on this error.  Current prefix is set to c:\users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm?

Comment: When using Yarn the module installs correctly.  Weird..